# How to migrate a VS2012 Azure Cloud Service Project to VS2013

Tags: azure, migration, visual-studio-2013

I have two ASP.NET MVC 4 projects created in VS2012. For each, I created an Azure deployment project and they are both deployed successfully to Azure. I got a new dev machine and started fresh with only VS2013 installed, hoping that, as advertised, I wouldn't have to go through the pain of migrations that would make the projects tied to this version. Well, that didn't turn out true, as Azure projects must be upgraded to v2.2 of the Azure .NET tools and API to be opened in VS2013.

On the first project, I installed the 2.2 tools and with a few other relatively minor adjustments, the project works fine. Now, on the second project, however, I can find no way to  perform the upgrade. When I opened the project in VS2013, it gave me a migration report saying that the Azure project was incompatible and the only solution offered was to install the 2.2 tools, which of course, has already been installed. I then decided to remove the existing azure deployment project and create a new one as I did before on vs2012, by right-clicking on the web project and choosing "Add Azure deployment project", which wires everything up automatically. Well, that menu item does not appear in the context menu on the web project.

Now, I'm at a loss for how to resolve this, other than installing VS2012 and forego taking advantage of the advances in VS2013. Does anyone have any suggestions how i can get an Azure deployment project working with this project?

(BTW, this is a must, because I am using the azure api to get config items out of the azure config.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it by installing the 2013 version of the Azure 2.2 SDK (found here). After doing this I was able to build and run the solution (without any conversion) in both VS2012 and VS2013.

UPDATE:

Try to add a new Azure Cloud Service project to your solution by right-clicking the solution > Add > New Project.

Under templates there should be a section named 'Cloud' with a project template named Windows Azure Cloud Service. When you select this template you should get a dialog where you can add Azure roles to your solution.

If you select ASP.NET web role, a new Web project will be created in your solution. If you don't select anything, you will get an empty Azure project to which you can add your existing MVC project (WebRole Project > Right click Roles > Web role project in solution).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I installed the 2.2 tools (with sdk) and it worked great for that one project, but as stated, couldn't perform the update for any other projects. My klunky workaround was to load the project on another machine (with only VS2012 installed), performed the 2.2 upgrade and it upgraded the second project properly, as it had on the first one, so now, all is good. Thankfully I didn't have more projects, as I was out of machines, 
;-)